# How to key press tab and delete at the same time on a browser using apple script?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, keypress

I'd like to create an apple script that can repeatedly press tab and delete while the focused on text in a browser.

I've tried the following to press tab and delete at the same time:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
repeat 99 times
    tell application "System Events"
        key down tab
        keystroke delete key
        key up
    end tell

    delay 2
end repeat
```

Attempt 2:

```
    tell application "System Events"
        key down {command down}
            key code 51 
            key code 48
        key up {command down}
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You can't press those keys together at the same time. Neither tab nor delete are commands. It's like asking the computer to type "a" and "b" at the same time.

Are you sure you need to press them simultaneously? It seems like you're trying to just press one right after the other.

Comment: okay, pressing tab and then quickly pressing delete as well works